# Explanation of notation (probability)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

Im working on a question from a book on probability theory. However I cant figure out what is meant with this notation:

First the introduction.
Let $X_1, X_2, …,$ be iid randoms variables, defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$, with distribution function $F$ of $X_1$.

Assume that $F(x) < 1$ for all $x $

Let $M_n = max\{X_1,..,X_n\}$

Now here is my question; what does this mean?

Show that $\left( M_n \to \infty \right) \in \mathbb{F}$

I would very much like to understand the notation such that I can try to solve it.

Comment: I simply read this as “$M_n\to\infty$” is an event (i.e., an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb F$)…

Comment: The notation is really not good, but it means that $\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty }M_n=\infty \right\}\in \mathbb F$ (i.e. that $ \left\{\lim_{n\to \infty }M_n=\infty \right\}$ is an event).

Comment: Is showing that it is an event the same as showing the limit is $\infty$?
I’ve tried to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(M_n \leq x) = 0$ for all values of $x$. 
I’m just not sure that this is showing what I want.

Comment: Let $n = 3.$ Express $F_3(x) = P(M_3 \le x)$ in terms of $F(x).$ Answer the question for $F_3.$ Generalize. // Hint: If the max of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is $\le x$ then we must have all three $X_i \le x.$ That involves an intersection. What does that have to do with with properties of $\mathbb{F}?$

Comment: Thanks @BruceET! I get it know.

Comment: Grad you were able to follow my trail of bread crumbs.